# Trying to set up remote git, pushing initial commit gives "git-receive-pack: not found"

Tags: git, push, nas

I'm trying to set up a git origin on my Synology DS212J NAS server.
When I try this command to push to the server:

```
git remote add nas ssh://username@nasip/volume1/path/to/repo/repo.git
git push nas master
```

I am first prompted with my password, which I enter.
Then I am given the following error:

```
sh: git-receive-pack: not found
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Does anyone know what this means or how I can fix it?

EDIT:
This is what I'm following, but I'm getting the error when I try to push to the remote.
http://rubypane.blogspot.com/2012/03/creating-new-git-repository-on-synology.html

Answer (score 4):

As che and others explained above this is a problem with the path settings on your synology NAS. Usually, your .profile and /etc/profile are parsed when logging in through ssh, but not so in this case. While this can be adjusted as explained by wonko at http://www.wonko.de/2010/04/set-up-git-on-synology-nas.html (step 6), I prefer not to allow users to change their environments. My proposed alternative is to simply create symlinks. Do the following:

```
cd /opt/bin
for gitfile in git* ; do ln -s /opt/bin/$gitfile /bin/$gitfile ; done
```

Remember to log in as root before issuing these commands.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like you don't have git installed on your remote box. Git uses it's own protocol on to of ssh, so you need to have binaries that will understand git objects on the other side as well.

The program your client is trying to run is `git-receive-pack`, so try to run in from the shell on your box. If that works you'll see something like

```
che@nok ~ $ git receive-pack
usage: git receive-pack <git-dir>
```

And if it does not:

```
-bash-4.0# git-receive-pack
-bash: git-receive-pack: command not found
```

If you have git there installed, you should try if `git receive-pack` works there. If it does you probably just need to symlink git to git-receive-pack somewhere in your path.

Running

```
cd `which git`
ln -si git git-receive-pack
```

under root might do it for you.

Comment: I did a bare repo init on the remote already, and yes I did install git on the remote (using this: http://www.wonko.de/2010/04/set-up-git-on-synology-nas.html)

Comment: @Jay, then the real problem is that in Unix, interactive and non-interactive logins (Git uses the latter) make the spawned shell read different startup scripts; supposedly you adjusted your `PATH` environment variable in a startup script which is read for interactive logins only. See [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files) for the `bash` case; other shells have similar semantics.

Comment: Actually, I'm able to get the "git receive-pack <git-dir>" result. However, when I try to do "git push nas master" from my local repo to the nas, I still get the same error as before.

Comment: I'm following these instructions exactly, but when I get to the push part I'm getting that "sh: git-receive-pack: not found" error. http://rubypane.blogspot.com/2012/03/creating-new-git-repository-on-synology.html

Comment: @che Yes.  When I login as my user and cd to the nas git directory, and type in "git-receive-pack" I get "usage: git receive-pack <git-dir>".  When I type in "git-upload-pack" I get "usage: git upload-pack [--strict] [--timeout=<n>] <dir>"

Comment: @Jay: I guess than the problem will be path setups for non-interactive logins, as kostix notes above. You may try to run `ssh me@my_box_ip git-receive-pack` from your local machine to reproduce the error without git, and then you'll probably have to play with path settings on your NAS.

Comment: @che I just tried running what you suggested, and got this result: "sh: git-receive-pack: not found"

Comment: @Jay: Then you'll have to look into Synology paths thing, I'm afraid.