# Why does “git push” to HP-UX fail on SSH URLs with “Function is not available”?

Tags: git, curl, hp-ux

Compare: [Why does "git fetch" fail on HTTPS URLs with "Function is not available" on HP-UX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16084971/why-does-git-fetch-fail-on-https-urls-with-function-is-not-available-on-hp-u)

Environment:  pushing from Linux client to HP-UX server

I added `export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libpthread.a git push` to my `.profile` on the server using the other thread as a baseline, but that didn't work.
There is no `/usr/lib/hpux32/libpthread.so`.

```
error: cannot create thread: Function is not available
```

Works fine pushing to Linux servers, so I know it must be environmental.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is:

Edit /etc/opt/ssh/sshd_config on the HP-UX server:

```
PermitUserEnvironment yes
```

Restart sshd.

Create ~/.ssh/environment for every git user on the HP-UX server:

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/ssh/bin:/usr/local/bin
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/hpux32/libpthread.so
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that git client does't source .profile files when pushing. Your environment variable is probably not set when you pushing.

see [Trying to set up remote git, pushing initial commit gives "git-receive-pack: not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786055/trying-to-set-up-remote-git-pushing-initial-commit-gives-git-receive-pack-not)